# Duplicate rows not being dropped after comparison of two dataframes in pandas

Tags: python, mysql, pandas

I have two dataframes in pandas. Where one is data coming from an external source and another is coming from a mysql db. Both have the same columns (info, date, link).

I am running `merge` query on it to drop duplicates so in a sense to compare the external one with what is already in the database and drop the duplicates in the external one before inserting into the db.

```
column_titles = [
            'Title',
            'PublishDate',
            'ExternalUrl'
]

params_list = ['2018-07-01 00:00:00']

df = dbData.read(select_article_news_data(), column_titles, params_list)

df_content = df['data'].rename(columns={'Title': 'info','PublishDate' : 'date','ExternalUrl': 'link'})


    sql_col_titles = [
            'info',
            'date',
            'link'

        ]

sql_df = dbData.read(select_article_news_mysql(), sql_col_titles, None, mysql=True)

sql_df = sql_df['data']


df_all = df_content.merge(sql_df.drop_duplicates(), on=['info', 'date', 'link'],
                  how='left', indicator=True )

df_all = df_all.loc[df_all['_merge'] == 'left_only']

new_df = df_all.drop(columns=['_merge'])

new_df.to_sql(con=cnx, name='news', if_exists='append', index=False)
```

`dbData.read` simply invokes the pandas `read_sql` method, and performs some other stuff that is not related and returns a dicitonary, where the result set is `df['data']`.

The error I am getting is initially I have 306 entries when the script is first run. After this when I run it again is get 404 and these extra entries are all duplicates. When comparing using a conditional everything is `True` so it should drop these duplicates.

I have used this method before and it works. Could it be to do with my renaming the column names for `df_content`?

Comment: Please post a working and fully executable minimum example.

Comment: @Scotty1-Just as I was going through writing something that can be executed, I think I have found the error. The `date` column is a timestamp format but some of them are adding on timezones. I have had an issue like this on something different before, so will try to remove that first and see if it works. If not I will post up an executable example.